# C++: using parameters with user input?

Tags: c++, parameters

I just started c++ and am just playing around with some of the things iv learned the first few days and this program i wrote has no real purpose other than trying to figure out how to use returnable parameters with user input. When i try to compile this the whole thing just goes bonkers. Whats wrong with it?

here is the code i wrote:

```
    #include <iostream>


// defining the Parameters of Add and Multply

 int add(int a, int b)
 {
 return a + b;
 }
 int multiply(int c, int d)
 {
 return c * d;
 }

 int main ()
{
using namespace std;

// user defines vairables

int x;
int y;
int w;
int z;

cout << "enter x value now:" << endl;
cin >> x >> endl;
cout << "enter y value now" << endl;
cin >> y >> endl;
cout << "enter w value now" << endl;
cin >> w >> endl;
cout << "enter z value now" << endl;`
cin >> z >> endl;

//computation of variables

cout << "computing x and y factors" << add(x, y) << endl;
cout << "computing w and z cordinates" << multiply(w, z) << endl;
cout << " " << endl;
cout << "final answer is:  " << add(x, y) + multiply(w, z) << endl;

cin.clear();
cin.ignore(255, '\n');
cin.get();


return 0;
}
```

Comment: Looks like copy/paste gone bad...

Comment: Indentation would be a good start.

Answer (score 1):

First: Since you are asking about compilation errors, You should be posting the exact compilation errors that you are encountering.

Your problem lies in statements like these:

```
cin >> z >> endl;
```

should be:

```
cin >> z;
```

You just need to read entered input variable in to a variable, using `cin` You are not inserting anything in to the stream. `endl` inserts a newline to the stream.

Besides there is a stray  ` on line number 32, You need to remove that.

Comment: that did it.. thanks a lot... i guess that makes since that cin cant have end1

Comment: @SeanHolt it's (`endl` as in `ENDL`, not a one).

Answer (score 0):

Yes apparently the program is fine... Just a small silly mistake as Als mentioned.
let me explain it a bit more.
**endl** is the character used to output a new line on the screen.. when you are taking input via **cin**, you cannot print something at the same time. cin is the standard input stream, not output stream.
if you want to print **endl**, you can do it like this.

cout << x << endl ;